# Why this result "-9 >> 2 = -3"

Tags: javascript

Why

`9 >> 2 = 2`

and

`-9 >> 2 = -3`

?

I mean, why not -2.

Comment: Why should it be `-2`?

Comment: Research bit shifting and two's complement binary reprentation.

Comment: isn't `1000 0000 ... 0000 1001` >> 2 = `1000 0000 ... 0000 0010` ?

Comment: But -9 is not `1000 ... 0000 1001`. It's `1111 ... 111 0111`. Look up two's complement. Nobody uses sign-magnitude (for integers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [bitwise operators page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators) on MDN -

*"The operands of all bitwise operators are converted to signed 32-bit integers in big-endian order and in two's complement format. Big-endian order means that the most significant bit (the bit position with the greatest value) is the left-most bit if the 32 bits are arranged in a horizontal line. **Two's complement format means that a number's negative counterpart (e.g. 5 vs. -5) is all the number's bits inverted (bitwise NOT of the number, a.k.a. one's complement of the number) plus one.**"*

Answer (score 1):

```
1001 (9) >> 2 = 10 (2)
```

[2's compliment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) 9 to get -9 and do the same:

```
0111 (-9) >> 2 = 01
```

2's compliment the result and you get `11` or 3, so the answer is -3

Answer (score 0):

```
-1 = 11111111
-2 = 11111110
-3 = 11111101
-4 = 11111100
..
-8 = 11111000
-9 = 11110111
```

thus

```
-9 >> 2 = -3
```